# Was Charles Haddon Spurgeon a five-point Calvinist?

Tags: reformed-theology

I think so, but some articles online indicates that he was a Fullerist.

If so, was "Fullerism" orthodox?
Ex: [here.](http://www.faithalone.org/journal/2006i/5_harmon.pdf)

Any thought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no doubt but that Spurgeon was a five point Calvinist:

http://weecalvin1509.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/chsindex.html

Spurgeon's own quotes affirming all the 5 points together and each of the 5 points individually. As for Andrew Fuller - In the foreward of his book on the Sovereignty of God, AW Pink described Fuller as "eminent and honored." See:

http://weecalvin1509.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/carey.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to our community. Two things real quick, the first is that you're required to disclose when you link to your own blog or website (though doing so is not a problem, we just need you to tell us it's yours). The second is that it would help greatly if you included some of the proof here via quotation, that way if you take your blog down or accidentally break the links the answer remains useful. Thanks for a good answer and your blog looks like a great resource.

Comment: So Fullerism is orthodox? I have not seen the conclusion yet.